# How Ethernet protocol is related to Ethernet types such 10BASE5?

Tags: ethernet, networking

I know that Ethernet is a Data Link Layer protocol which specifies how the communication takes place b/w nodes in LAN defined by standard **IEEE 802.3**. I came across a book in which there were different types of Ethernet to name a few.

1. 10BASE2 (Thin Ethernet)
2. 10BASE5 (Thick Ethernet)
3. 10BASET

Are these all different Ethernet types are referencing to different version of Ethernet standard or it is different technologies that Ethernet can be used over defined in Ethernet Standard **IEEE 802.3**.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IEEE 802.3 Ethernet defines both *physical layer* variants and the general frame format for the *data link layer*. The variants you've quoted are quite ancient - 10BASE5 is 40 years old, 10BASE-T 30 years.

You can find an up-to-date list of Ethernet physical layer variants [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_physical_layer).

The standard is constantly amended to by new variants, improvements etc. (e.g. recently by IEEE 802.3cu for some 100 and 400 Gbit/s variants over single-mode fiber) and regularly recompiled into a complete set, the latest being IEEE 802.3-2018 with 802.3-2022 in the works.

On the data link layer, the basic frame format has been largely unchanged, providing excellent backward compatibility. Numerous options have been added however, perhaps the most prominently being IEEE 802.1q VLAN and 802.1ad QinQ tags. Also, the bridging/switching functions have vastly expanded